# Abortar uma requisição Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Em uma situação onde uso o `ASP.NET MVC`, tem como cancelar uma requisição `AJAX` dependendo da resposta de um modal? Estou fazendo algo assim:

```
function atualizaStatus(sel, id) {
    var $status = sel.value;
    var $idAluno = id;

    var ajax = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: '@Url.Action("AtualizaStatus", "Turmas")',
        data: { id: $idAluno, status: $status },
        beforeSend: function () {
            bootbox.confirm({
                title: "Confirma",
                locale: "br",
                message: "Deseja alterar status do aluno?",
                callback: function (result) {
                    if (result == false) {
                        ajax.abort();
                        bootbox.hideAll();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            })
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Algo deu errado, tente novamente mais tarde.")
        }
    });
}
```

Esse `bootbox` é um modal personalizado do estilo de confirm (ok e cancelar).

Na lógica esse `beforeSend` era pra executar antes de enviar o pedido ao `Controller`, porém quando faço `debug` de quando ele passa pelo `beforeSend`, ele manda o `request` para o `Controller` e só depois ele chama o modal, antes mesmo de esperar a resposta do usuário.

Porque isso ocorre e como contornar essa situação? Ou seja como fazer para o sistema esperar a resposta do modal e só depois repassar ao `Controller` a requisição ou cancelar a mesma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta você inverter a ordem, do jeito que você fez, o `beforeSend` executa anteriormente porém ele não vai esperar o `callback` do modal.

```
function atualizaStatus(sel, id) {
    var $status = sel.value;
    var $idAluno = id;

    bootbox.confirm({
        title: "Confirma",
        locale: "br",
        message: "Deseja alterar status do aluno?",
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result == false) {
                bootbox.hideAll();
                return false;
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                url: '@Url.Action("AtualizaStatus", "Turmas")',
                data: { id: $idAluno, status: $status },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Algo deu errado, tente novamente mais tarde.")
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```